# is there a way to change elements of a page before opening it

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, bootstrap-4

I have designed a page to be used as a tool. I am getting some challenges here since my experience is very little in the field and im only new. 
- my goal is to change values of an element on a page that is not open yet.
- is there a function i can make on current page to change the values of the element on the next page to preset it to some static numbers or some of them are dynamic

I dont know how to manipulate something that is not open yet, i dont even know if that's something possible. I was able to change elements on my open current page, but dont know how to change something on the next page if i click on one of the links

```
        <a href="https://rex.reportexecdirect.com/intelligarde/CESIReportExec/Reporting/ParkingPermit.aspx?groupid=174" class="btn btn-info mx-1" role="button">Park Property Management</a>
        <a href="https://rex.reportexecdirect.com/intelligarde/CESIReportExec/Reporting/ParkingPermit.aspx?groupid=121" class="btn btn-info mx-1" role="button">Millgate Manor</a>
        <a href="https://rex.reportexecdirect.com/intelligarde/CESIReportExec/Reporting/ParkingPermit.aspx?groupid=166" class="btn btn-info mx-1" role="button">Weston Towers</a>
        <a href="https://rex.reportexecdirect.com/intelligarde/CESIReportExec/Reporting/ParkingPermit.aspx?groupid=290" class="btn btn-info mx-1" role="button">Kingston</a>
        <a href="https://rex.reportexecdirect.com/intelligarde/CESIReportExec/Reporting/ParkingPermit.aspx?groupid=190" class="btn btn-info mx-1" role="button">Region Of Peel</a>
```

so i expect to click on one of the links and when the link opens some elements in the links i need them to be filled with some values that are static always

Comment: you have to run different js on each page. the first one makes a note of adjustments to be made. the 2nd one looks for notes and reacts accordingly.

Comment: You could pass in the values as a query parameter if you really needed to and have them interpreted by the Javascript running on the other page. This is not quite "before" but if you run it as blocking code, it might as well appear this way to the end user.

Comment: oh god this sounds totally above my capabilities, i only started this project with a small simple idea now im here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly influence the content of another page with JavaScript in the current page. That would have very big security concerns.

However, you could indirectly influence the content if you have access to the source for both pages, and can add JavaScript to both of them. Then, as some comments suggested, you can for example use search paramaters in the link url to pass along information.
(Search parameters are the stuff that comes at the end of a url sometimes and looks something like `?name=john&id=555`)

You can read more about about working with search parameters in JavaScript here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Don't get discouraged! You're capabilities will grow as you try to make things work. (That's almost the only time they will grow.)

**A word of caution!**

Please be very careful when using search parameters to modify or display content on a page as there are some real security concerns involved. Never display anything from the search parameters directly on the page without validating the input first. A good way to handle dynamic content based on search parameters, at least if you know the possible options available, is to have some `if .. else` statements or maybe a `switch` block that you try to match the search parameters against, and simply not display anything at all if the content of the parameter does not match any input that you're expecting.

Comment: i have access to my own page, but i dont have any access to the source code of the page that opens by clicking the links.

Comment: so yeah the correct words to use is passing. I am trying to pass information/values from my created page to the pages/links that opens from my page. Again i dont have access to the source code of that page bcuz im working on this voluntarily without permission from anyone

Comment: @MinoLevon You can always pass along information in parameters in the URL by adding them at the end, but unless the code for the other page (server-side or client-side) is expecting the parameters that you send, then they will likely have no effect at all on the page. If you are trying to create a proof of concept for an idea you have, then I would suggest making your own copy of the page you want to send information to, and alter the code of that page as you wish. (You can get the source code from any HTML page by right clicking in the browser and click 'View page source')

Comment: yes ! i see what you are suggesting its logical. I am creating a page that can be used for the company im working with to help the dispatchers auto-fill some static information and dates, and shortcut some addresses fillings for parking permits.

Comment: when i say shortcut addresses filling for parking permits. I mean by reducing the time the dispatcher is on phone call. There are over 100 different addresses in the city and my company is taking over the parking permits, if I get to make the addresses fill in the blank easier for the team, it would increase the work efficiency

Comment: so you might ask why is it hard to fill in addresses in the textBox element. the answer for your question will be example below of how the address looks like and what is my suggestion to make it faster 
example:
Region : Property manager name : actual address

Comment: so instead of that long sausage line I want to created a simple drop down list with the addresses and when the user(dispatcher) clicks on one of the names i want to create that long sausage string and pass it to the next page into the address textBox

Comment: @MinoLevon It sounds like a good idea to try to help your co-workers get more work done! You could maybe help them a bit even if you can't pass through any information to the other page. You can create the drop downs, and simply have a text input that displays the selected value of the drop downs in the 'sausage line' format. Then your co-workers could just copy&paste the text. It would be almost as fast as passing it on to the next page. Would that work?

Comment: oh so you are suggesting me to make it when the selection of the address is made the `sausage line` will be copied to clipboard and the user will just paste it into the textBox ?
I've thought about that and it might be very much possible, but i still feel like im cheating myself :D

Comment: @MinoLevon Yes, exactly :) I don't think it's cheating! Sometimes you don't have a choice in the way you implement things because of third party software/websites that you have no control over. Try to make it and show it to your co-workers! Good luck :)

Comment: i made what you suggested, but im here struggling with the dropdown list menu. Dropdown lists on click its not copying the value of the item to clipboard, but it works on regular buttons. It's such a bummer i dont know what to use to be able to show the items in a dropdown list fashion

Comment: @MinoLevon Copying to clipboard is restricted in different ways in different browsers. Your best bet to make the page work in any browser is to have drop downs for selecting and then a 'copy' button that copies the content to the clipboard.